# Regex allow a string to only contain numbers 0 - 9 and limit length to 45

Tags: regex, string, string-matching

I am trying to create a regex to have a string only contain `0-9` as the characters and it must be at least 1 char in length and no more than `45`. so example would be `00303039` would be a match, and `039330a29` would not.

So far this is what I have but I am not sure that it is correct

```
[0-9]{1,45}
```

I have also tried

```
^[0-9]{45}*$
```

but that does not seem to work either. I am not very familiar with regex so any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 177):

You are almost there, all you need is start anchor (`^`) and end anchor (`$`):

```
^[0-9]{1,45}$
```

`\d` is short for the character class `[0-9]`. You can use that as:

```
^\d{1,45}$
```

The anchors force the pattern to match *entire* input, not just a *part* of it.

---

Your regex `[0-9]{1,45}` looks for 1 to 45 digits, so string like  `foo1` also get matched as it contains `1`.

`^[0-9]{1,45}` looks for 1 to 45 digits but these digits must be at the ***beginning*** of the input. It matches `123` but also `123foo`

`[0-9]{1,45}$` looks for 1 to 45 digits but these digits must be at the ***end*** of the input. It matches `123` but also `foo123`

`^[0-9]{1,45}$` looks for 1 to 45 digits but these digits must be ***both*** at the start and at the end of the input, effectively it should be ***entire*** input.

Comment: ahh thank you, can you explain what the carrot ^ and $ do for this expression? Just start and end of a string?

Comment: @NewToRegEx - yes. They do not allow any other characters appear before or after the match of 1-45 digits.

Comment: If you live in a unicode world (which most people do), `\d` is **not** the same as `[0-9]`. `\d` allows for `௪` etc (and thousands more) to match; `[0-9]` does not.

Answer (score 14):

The first matches any number of digits within your string (allows other characters too, i.e.: "039330a29"). The second allows only 45 digits (and not less). So just take the better from both:

```
^\d{1,45}$
```

where `\d` is the same like `[0-9]`.

Comment: If you live in a unicode world (which most people do), `\d` is **not** the same as `[0-9]`. `\d` allows for `௪` etc (and thousands more) to match; `[0-9]` does not.

Answer (score 14):

Use this regular expression if you don't want to start with zero:

```
^[1-9]([0-9]{1,45}$)
```

If you don't mind starting with zero, use:

```
^[0-9]{1,45}$
```

Comment: Helpful for the ability to cut out 0!

Answer (score 5):

A combination of both attempts is probably what you need:

```
^[0-9]{1,45}$
```

Answer (score 5):

codaddict has provided the right answer. As for what you've tried, I'll explain why they don't make the cut:

- `[0-9]{1,45}` is almost there, however it matches a 1-to-45-digit string *even if it occurs within another longer string containing other characters*. Hence you need `^` and `$` to restrict it to an exact match.
- `^[0-9]{45}*$` matches an exactly-45-digit string, repeated 0 or any number of times (`*`). That means the length of the string can only be 0 or a multiple of 45 (90, 135, 180...).

Answer (score 2):

`^[0-9]{1,45}$` is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Rails doesnt like the using of ^ and $ for some security reasons , probably its better to use \A and \z to set the beginning and the end of the string

Answer (score -1):

For this case **word boundary** (\b) can also be used instead of start anchor (^) and end anchor ($):

```
\b\d{1,45}\b
```

`\b` is a position between \w and \W (non-word char), or at the beginning or end of a string.