# how to match a input value with the regular expression in dynamics crm 2011?

Tags: regex, dynamics-crm-2011, customization, dynamics-crm

At the contact form I have a field name as Extension (new_ext). and at the onChnage event I want to do check weather the user has enter the number or anything else. I have the following piece of code.

```
function formatPhone(phonenum)
{
var ext =phonenum.getEventSource().getValue();
  var reg = /^[0-9]$/;
if(ext.match(reg))
{
alert("Valid");
}
else
{
alert("invalid");
}
}
```

It returns me always invalid even if I enter a letter or a number or both.

I want to seek your kind suggestions and help regarding this.

Comment: your regex matches 1 digit only. If there is more than 1 digit it will return false.  I think you want `/^[0-9]+$/`.

Comment: You should strip all non-digits like so: `phonenum.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '')` then further validate the numbers/length as a legitimate phone number. You also may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation) useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one `"^\d+$"`, just check for null values before if you need to.

Already asked here [Regex allow a string to only contain numbers 0 - 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968049/regex-allow-a-string-to-only-contain-numbers-0-9-and-limit-length-to-45)

Comment: Note: `\d` is **not** the same as `[0-9]`. `\d` allows for things like `"௪"`. `[0-9]` does not.