# Can I use the different events of Javascript in CRM 2011?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, microsoft-dynamics

With respect to my previous [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612600/how-to-match-a-input-value-with-the-regular-expression-in-dynamics-crm-2011), I want to ask another question that is Can I use the `onKeyPress` or similar events which could be fire on key press? Because CRM 2011 allows only `onChange` and `onLoad` events.

So I want to seek your  kind suggestions regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can the only time you need to make sure you use CRM js functions is when it comes to getting/setting entity values etc...  But if it has to do with UI events etc.. you can use normal javascript events.

CRM applies rules and required field validation upon submit so you aren't interfering with any plumbing.