# sublime regular expression search

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I need to search for all strings like this "264676343" in sublime text editor, 9 numbers between "". I try to use this "0-9" but not work... please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968049/regex-allow-a-string-to-only-contain-numbers-0-9-and-limit-length-to-45

Answer (score 2):

the `0-9` searches for digits. That is good. But you need to find a sequence of digits, so:

`[0-9]+`
take a look: https://regex101.com/r/yJ2rA8/1

and if you want to have EXACTLY 9 digits, then this should do the trick:

`[0-9]{9}`
take a look: https://regex101.com/r/aC7oF9/2

As per MattDMo comment, you may also use a shorthand for digits `\d` instead of `0-9`:

```
\d{9}
\d+
```

Comment: Why use `[0-9]+`? Just use `\d+` or `\d{9}`.

Comment: You might wan to add that OP is looking for digits in double quotes (see the question), so finally: `"\d+"`.