# How to restrict number field with 10 digits only

Tags: asp.net, regex, html, user-input

I am trying to create a text field where One can type his/her mobile numbers 10 digits only. NO spacing dash coma or alphabets.  I tried using the following regex from the given link but it is not working. I am using chrome and even tried on fiddler. 
I took reference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968049/regex-allow-a-string-to-only-contain-numbers-0-9-and-limit-length-to-45) code.

```html
 <input type="number" pattern="^[0-9]{1,10}$" title="adc" />
```

Comment: You need to use `type="text"`. And remove the `^` and `$`, and  since you need 10 digit, replace `{1,4}` with `{10}`.

Comment: edited my question with my code

Comment: using this I am not restricted to just right 10 digits..  I can write as many as I want :( This is the problem. I can show you fiddler if you want

Comment: Is Тодор's solution enough for you? Or do you need an HTML5 specific answer?

Comment: HTML specific  answer

Comment: Really just a side note: reality will probably kick in hard when the first user is trying to input his number in international format, starting with `+`. Just remember you've been warned when it happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `type="text"` and then use `\d{10}` regex. Note that a regex validation does not work when your `<input>` *type* is *number*. Also, the regex inside the `pattern` attribute is anchored by default, that is why you do not need the anchors  (`^` for the start of string and `$` for the end of string). The `pattern="\d{10}"` regex will be translated into `/^(?:\d{10})$/` pattern that matches a string consisting of exactly 10 digits.

```css
input:valid {
  color: navy;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1"> 
 <input type="text" pattern="\d{10}" title="Error: 10 digits are required." onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode &gt;= 48 && event.charCode &lt;= 57"  />
 <input type="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

To disallow a non-numeric input, add `onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"` to the `<input>` element.

Comment: here is your work in js fiddle and It s NOT working and also accepting alphabets 
https://jsfiddle.net/z5om6ozh/1/

Comment: You can *type* anything, but not *submit* anything. That is the purpose of the `pattern` attribute. It is a *final, on-submit* input validation. Disallowing the non-numeric input does not have to be done with regex, see my update.

Comment: Okay This makes sense .. I will use this . as the alternate Thanks :)

Comment: If you find my answer working for you, please consider accepting it, and upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try validating it in the controller with an attribute like this

```
[RegularExpression("[0-9]{10}", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid Number")]
```

Comment: can't I do it in HTML5 ?

Comment: You can, but proper ASP.NET validation is made on the backend, not the front-end. By using front-end validation users can easily modify the dom with the developer tools of your browser and submit wrong data.

Comment: That's  a good tip but this is a personal in house system i was just wondering that is this possible or not. I could not do this. therefore asked here..  :)

Comment: If its like that, then you can simply use something like this:

Comment: <form>
    <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{1,10}" title="adc" />
    <input type="submit">
    </form>

Answer (score 0):

use the following attr on controller :-

[RegularExpression("[0-9]{10}", ErrorMessage = "Enter Valid number")]

Or:
1- make input field's type is number

2- type the following Js

$('#idInputTxt').keypress(function (e) {

```
  if (this.value.length == 10|| (e.which > 57 && e.which < 65) || 
     (e.which > 90 && e.which < 97) ||  (e.which > 122) ||(e.which < 48 || e.which > 57))
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay I will If there is no solution to do it in HTML5 ?? Is there any? Please

Comment: I updated my answer.. please check it again .. thanks